# How to communicate between ASPX and WinForms

Tags: asp.net, winforms

How can I send commands to a WinForms application from an ASPX web page? We have already explored executing the WinForms application with different command line parameters but wanted something more smart.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a web server within your application that listens for HTTP `GET` and/or `POST` commands and acts appropriately. Then use AJAX to send request, i.e., http://localhost/myapp/?command=print&file=teletubies.jpg

Your web server, which is just a program that listens on port 80 and sends responses according to the very simple HTTP protocol, within your application then parses the requested URL and decides that it should `print` the file `teletubies.jpg` based on the query string in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Web pages (whether running asp.net or a competing platform) are *always* **reactive**. They receive commands (requests) and respond.  They are not *proactive*, and don't send commands.  This is how the core technology on which the internet is built works.

This means is you want an asp.net page to send a message to a client app, the only way to do it is for the client app to frequently poll the page, possibly using `System.Net.WebClient`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way this can be done due to security.  I know I wouldn't want people to be able to access the running applications on MY machine from their web app.

Comment: who said it's THEIR web app?